# Is a bowl of soup "harder" to spill than a bowl of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, viscosity

*Is it really harder to spill a bowl of soup (water + stuff) than a bowl of water of the same quantity?*

### Explanation:

Intuitively, one would think that spilling soup requires **additional clumsiness**, but why is that the case?

My first guess was the whole thing is inertia related. I though that as the plate is (accidentally) laterally accelerated, the **stuff** in the soup react faster thus reaching the critical side of the bowl while displacing water as they do so. As a result, water gets moved away from the *dangerous* side and the entire system is made more *spill-proof*.

Another guess would be that the **stuff** acts as many small barriers that obstruct the movement of water making it more difficult for it to reach *spill-levels*. More difficult as in requiring more time or higher g-forces.

PS: The question came to a colleague of mine while transporting a soup with noodles but it can be expanded to anything (e.g., carrots, potatoes, etc..).

---

**Edit**: I am assuming that the viscosity of the water in the soup does not change.

Comment: If the stuff is small enough to increase the viscosity then yes that soup is not as easily spilled.

Comment: You are basically asking for a microscopic explanation of why the viscosity of soup is higher than that of water.

Comment: I think if you assume that viscosity of the water and the soup is the same then basically your question is equivalent to comparing water to water with, say, a couple of coins, glass beads and electric wires inside. I think if there is any difference between soup and water it should be because of the viscosity difference between two caused by dissolved nutrient and undissolved fat.

Comment: Since the soup bowl is (usually) hot, I find it easier to spill because I’m holding it gingerly to not burn my fingers.

Comment: @physicopath That would be correct.